# Pyspark Archives no module name error, (Using sparkmagic, livy for connect pyspark)

Tags: python, pyspark, livy

When i connect spark Session using Jupyter notebook (using Sparkmagic), Livy.
I added venv archives (in spark magic config.json)

in venv, include pyyaml, hdfs library

And i `import hdfs` in jupyter notebook with pyspark kernel , Error raise no module name.

I already did below link
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/user_guide/python_packaging.html

How can i solve it?

Sorry for that I can't capture the image,

Plus, Let me teach the differences

- spark.pyspark.python
- spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON
- spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON

solve env for pyspark

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)